# Is there a diverging series in $o(1/n)$

Tags: real-analysis, sequences-and-series, asymptotics, divergent-series

Is there a function $f : \mathbb{N} \to \mathbb{R}^+$ in $o(1/n)$ s.t.
$\Sigma_{i=0}^\infty f(n)$ diverges?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes. let $g(n)=\ln\ln n$. Then $g(n+1)-g(n)\approx g'(n)=\frac 1n\cdot\frac1{\ln n}\in o(\frac1n)$. Thus letting $f(n)=g(n+1)-g(n)$, you have your example

Answer (score 4):

Try $$\sum_{i=2}^\infty \frac{1}{n \log(n) }$$

Comment: And use the integral test.